# GCD of two elements in the ring of residue classes modulo 20

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the ring of residue classes modulo 20, the book says that the greatest common divisor of residue classes $9$ and $18$ is $9$. But I am getting $1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19$ .

Comment: $1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19$ are all residues that are coprime to $20$.

Comment: You mean all co-prime residue classes are GCDs?

Comment: No, $(1,20)=(3,20)=...=(19,20)=1$.  $(9,18)=9$

Comment: But how come $(9,18)$ is not 1. $1|9$ and $9|1$ -> $1$ and $9$ are associates -> If $9$ is the gcd, then so is $1$. Same is true for all numbers I'm getting as answer. What's wrong with my argument?

Comment: the residue class of 18 is the same as the residue class of 2 times the residue class  of 9.  Both residue classes are thus multiples of the residue class of 9.  The idea is the same for integers.....

Comment: Correct. So the gcd is not just $9$ but all the above listed integers. Right?

Comment: GCD is defined only up to unit(invertible) factors, so gcd $\sim unit \iff $ gcd $\sim 1.\,$ [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2939562/242) for further discussion.

Comment: I made an error in the previous comment. I meant " So the gcd is not just residue class of $9$ but all the above listed residue classes, Right?"

Comment: @Anuj what text are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the divisibility graph of the classes, where $a\to b$ means $a|b$.

[image: divisibility graph]

We don't have to list all the associates, which are in these collections:

$\{1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19\}$

$\{2,6,14,18\}$

$\{4,12,8,16\}$

$\{5,15\}$

$\{10\}$

As far as divisibility is concerned, we don't need to distinguish among associates.

Because of the direction I happened to draw my graph, the GCD's are actually the lowest thing on top of the two given elements. $9$ and $18$ correspond to $1$ and $2$ respectively, so $1$ is the greatest common divisor. This makes sense since $1$ and $9$ are already units.

Comment: So the $(9,18)$ is any residue class present in equivalence class of $9$, right?

Comment: @Anuj Yes, if by "equivalence class" you're referring to the divisibility class, not the class of integers mod $20$.