# Simple algebra question (find the LCM of the polynomials by factoring)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

First of all, I am so embarrassed by this.  I am tutoring this kid in math and this question came up: *Find the LCM of* $y^2 - 81$ *and* $9 - y$, which factor into $(y + 9)(y - 9)$ and $-(y - 9)$

My answer: $-(y+9)(y-9)$

Her book's answer: $(y+9)(y-9)$

My question: Why is the negative left off?  Isn't it ($-1$) a factor of the second binomial?

Comment: gcds & lcms in polynomial rings are defined only up to unit (invertible) factors. For polynomials (over fields) they usually normalized to be *monic*, i.e lead coef $= 1.\,$ [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2939562/242) for more on such *unit normalization*.

Answer (score 4):

Both answers are valid. Any nonzero constant can be factored out of any polynomial.

Technically speaking, finding the $\operatorname{lcm}$ of two elements is an action done in a ring. If it exists, the $\operatorname{lcm}$ is unique up to multiplication of a *unit* of the ring, i.e. an invertible element.

In this case, all nonzero constants are units in a polynomial ring over a field (here $\mathbb{R}$), so multiplying by a constant still gives an $\operatorname{lcm}$. If we instead are considering these polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$, there's still no problem since $-1$ is a unit.

Comment: "all *nonzero* constants are units".   Also better to restrict to domains vs. rings since divisibility theory in general rings is more complex, e.g. associates are no longer the same as unit multiples; furthermore the notions of associate and irreducible bifurcate into a few inequivalent notions in use.

Comment: Good point. Could you edit to add the nuance for rings vs domains? My ring theory's a bit rusty.