# Why the modular arithmetic requires modulus to be an integer greater than one?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) article in Wikipedia tells that the modulus in modular arithmetic should be an integer greater than $1$.

But I can easily imagine a similar algebra where equivalence classes are defined as $a\equiv a+n$ or $a\equiv a+n/2$, for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

As such, the requirement that modulus should be integer greater than $1$ seems artificial to me.

Comment: Positive normalization of a modulus is merely for convenience - just like for denominators, and similarly for  [unit normalization of gcds](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2939562/242).  Further, as you mention, we can also consider [fractional ideals and modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_ideal), but they are not usually introduced in a first course on number theory.

Comment: The question is about the modulus, not the remainder. You can have modulus of 1 or even complex ones like in $$\exp(x) = \exp(y) \iff x\equiv y \mod 2\pi i$$

Comment: @emacs Who mentioned remainders? At Anixx: are you familiar with ideals or modules?

Comment: @BillDubuque no