# Proof of two ideals are equal

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, ideals, computational-algebra, monomial-ideals

How can we prove that the ideals $\,I=(x_1+x_2, x_2^2)\,$ and $\,J=(x_1+x_2, x_1^2)$ are equal?

I was thinking of looking at $ {\rm Mon}(I) = {\rm Mon}(J)\,$. Thank you.

Comment: What is Mon ?...

Comment: monomial ideals

Comment: note $I\ni (x_1-x_2)(x_1+x_2)+x_2^2=x_1^2$

Answer (score 2):

In fact you just have to show that $x_1^2 \in I$. Consider $x_1(x_1+x_2) - x_2^2$.

Answer (score 1):

As in the mod reduction step in the Euclidean algorithm for the gcd, for a polynomial $\,f(t)\in \Bbb Z[t]$

$$\begin{align}\bmod\, &x\!+\!y\!:\,\ x\equiv -y\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{f(x)\equiv f(-y)}\\[.4em]
\Longrightarrow\ \ &\!\!(x\!+\!y,\, \color{#c00}{f(x)}) \,=\, (x\!+\!y,\, \color{#c00}{f(-y)})\\[.4em]
{\rm by}\ \ \ \ \ &\!\!(a, \color{#c00}{b}) = (a,\color{#c00}{b'})\ \ \,{\rm if}\,\ \ \color{#c00}{b\equiv b'}\!\!\!\pmod{\!a} 
\end{align}\qquad $$

OP is special case $\,f(t) = t^2.\,$ Generally for ideals - just as for gcds - the ideal is preserved by reducing a generator modulo another or, more generally, [by unimodular transformations](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1185974/242).