# Write $(x-5, 3)$ as a principle ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I'm trying to familiarize myself with ideals and principle ideals but I'm having some problems when it comes to writing principle ideals when they're not explicitly principle. For example I would like to write $(x-5, 3)$ as a principle ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$. I know that it is possible to write $(x-5, 3)=(f)$ for $f\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$ because $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ is a PID, but I can't seem to be able to find such an $f$.
I know that $(x-5,3)=\{(x-5)g+3h:g,h\in\mathbb{Q}[X]\}$, but I don't know how this would help.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: this ideal contains an invertible element...

Comment: Wouldn't all constant polynomials of $(x-5,3)$ have invertible elements?

Comment: Yes, and when can an ideal contain an invertible element?

Comment: More generally $\,(a,b) = (b)\,$ if $\,b\mid a\,$ (e.g. when $b$ is a unit - which divides *everything*. This is a special case of [ideal mod reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3881842/242) (when it mods out to $0)\ \ $