# Why should the sign of remainder be same as dividend?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I was reading binary division from [this](http://sabercomlogica.com/en/ebook/the-division-algorithm/) site and this statement came across that **"remainder will have the same sign as the dividend"**. But why? Like from the utmost conceptual level, the very basic idea of remainders and negative numbers.

Comment: It is only a convention followed by some [and not all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder#In_programming_languages).

Comment: Indeed, in number theory it is much more useful to adopt the convention that the remainder is always nonnegative (and strictly less than the dividend). Example: https://study.com/academy/lesson/number-theory-divisibility-division-algorithm.html

Comment: But I even had this question in my 3rd-year undergrad paper of Computer Architecture. I couldn't just write that it's the convention. I had to think. That's why I asked it here.

Comment: But, but, but, but, but, your question has that answer whether you like it or not.

Comment: @GregMartin, I think you meant to say divisor, not dividend. (And also, how can the remainder be both nonnegative and strictly less than the dividend if the dividend, whatever it is, is negative? Presumably you meant strictly less than the absolute value of the divisor.)

Comment: There are various conventions in use, e.g. see [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/730531/242) to a prior question on this topic for some links, and see the many Linked questions there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to hazard a guess at why someone might adopt a convention that the remainder should have the same sign as the dividend. (As others have noted, the usual convention, when writing $n=qd+r$ is that $0\le r\lt|d|$, where, to fix terminology, $n$ is called the *dividend*, $q$ the *quotient*, $d\not=0$ the *divisor*, and $r$ the *remainder*. This convention is convenient for most number-theoretic purposes, although occasionally one wants to use the convention $-|d|/2\lt r\le |d|/2$.)

Let's start with a non-controversial example: $17$ divided by $5$. No one, I hope, objects to writing

$$17=3\cdot5+2$$

for the answer.  Now the *easiest* thing to do, if we put a negative sign in front of the $17$, is to write

$$-17=-3\cdot5-2$$

which we can interpret as either

$$-17=(-3)\cdot5-2$$

if we are dividing $-17$ by $5$, or as

$$-17=3\cdot(-5)-2$$

if we are dividing $-17$ by $-5$.  (The final combination of signs, $17$ divided by $-5$, is $17=(-3)\cdot(-5)+2$.)

In other words, the convention used in the OP's link begins by taking absolute values of both the dividend and the divisor, does the non-controversial calculation to get absolute values for the quotient and remainder, and then inserts *signs* in the appropriate places to turn $|n|=|q||d|+|r|$ into $n=qd+r$. The key here is that the final adjustment doesn't affect the *digits* of any of the numbers, only the numbers' signs. Given the link's computer-sciencey nature, that makes sense as a desirable feature for a convention.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very important convention since we usually take our dividends to be positive. This is also in other contexts called the modulus, and the remainder the residue. Thus given a modulus $d> 0$ and an integer $n,$ we have that there are always integers $q$ and $r\ge 0$ such that $$n=qd+r.$$ whatever negativity is absorbed by the first part, in particular with the quotient $q.$

Comment: negative residues are sometimes used for magnitude advantages in hand computation by contrast.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Of course they are. My point is that they're more usually taken in their positive incarnations, especially when referred to in definitions and proofs as opposed to applications.